# how to display items i want on a toast?

Tags: android, listview, toast

my first time doing an app on android. i have 4 strings and a lisview.i want to display the strings whenever user press the items on the listview on a toast. 
can any one help me on this ?

For eg: there are Event 1 ,event 2 and event 3 on my list view.
        and when user press event 1. it will display the date, time , venue for that event.

```
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Context context = getApplicationContext();



            Toast.makeText(context,
                       "Date: "+date  +"                                   " +"Tme: "+ time, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(context,"hi",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        });
```

This is the codes for extracting it out from googleCalendar

```
         date = contentResult[0].substring(10, 21);

         time = contentResult[0].substring(21, 36);

         location = contentResult[2].substring(6);

         description = contentResult[4].substring(18);






         eventTitle[i] = name;
         eventDate[i] = date;
         eventTime[i] = time;
         eventVenue[i] = location;
         eventContent[i] = description;






         event[i] = name + "                                        "  + "Date: " +date + "                                   " + "Time: " +time + "              " +" Location:"+ location+  "Event Description:"+ description ;
```

Comment: Take your toast, arrange various yummy items on it. I personally like ham and swiss, arranged in parallel on top of one another.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set your lists onItemClickListener like so:

```
private OnItemClickListener mMessageClickedHandler = new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        // Display a messagebox.
        Toast.makeText(this,"You clicked something!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};

myList.setOnItemClickListener(mMessageClickedHandler);
```

Of course you would have to input your own data (I'm guessing from a database or web service) to the Toast message indicating the date, time, and location of the event.

EDIT: In response to your comment, it sounds like you are new to Android development. You might want to check out [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html) great tutorial to learn how to use SQLite, and the Android SDK in general.

Comment: how do i input my own data ? i need help on that.

Comment: You should state that in your question as it is essential. Also please post what you have tried (code wise).